# I am saving an image using $image->store('/projects/images');, but i can't display it any how in the view blade template

Tags: laravel

I am saving an image using $image->store('/projects/images');, but i can't display it any how in the view blade template,

Here the code for saving it :

```
foreach($request->images as $image){
                    $imagePath= $image->store('/projects/images');

                     $project->projectImages()->create([
                         //'project_id' => $project->id,
                         'url' => $imagePath,
                     ]);
                     }
```

I am using this code for showing in the view blade template

```
<img src="/storage/app/public/{{$project->images->first()['url']}}" alt="img" class="cover-image fit-image">
```

The images is storing in storage/app/public/projects
the data stored in my images table is like "projects/images/5.jpg"

Comment: why not use HTML img tag ? And you should give more detail about `$image->store()` method. Is it some package or your own custom object?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be accessing your storage folder directly from the view. Instead, create a symbolic link from public/storage to storage/app/public. You can use this command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

You can then access your images with

```
{{ asset('storage/'.$project->images->first()['url']) }}
```

See [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#the-public-disk)